# There's no bug report when my application crashed on android oreo 8.1

Tags: android, debugging, report

When I was using MIUI 9, I always got an error report when my application crashed, so I can find where the error easily.
But now I changed my rom to a custom rom(LineageOS oreo) and now I can't find that error report anymore. 
Can anyone provide some solution?
the error report looked like this ( attach.en.miui.com/forum/201410/04/180718hl8zzt3jjyvs3ot6.png )

Comment: i just realized that the stack trace is placed in android monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) as it allows you to send an email (to yourself) containing the Stacktrace and other relevant information as soon as your app crashes.

See: [ACRA Setup](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)

Comment: the report shows java error log, looked like this ( http://attach.en.miui.com/forum/201410/04/180718hl8zzt3jjyvs3ot6.png )
is this ACRA that you mean?
it was defaultly there in my miui rom

Comment: No not really but it allows you send an email which contains the stacktrace.

Its an additional step but at least it allows you receive it.

Comment: Why dont you use the stock Android debugger ?

Comment: how to i use it? sorry i really am new to android programming

Comment: @Phiard Please take a look at https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup.

It shows all the necessary steps to get started.